# No output over SSH before waiting for input via scanf()

Tags: c, ssh, scanf, fflush

I have a file called `get_int.c` on a remote Unix system, containing the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int input;

    printf("Give an integer: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d", &input);

    printf("Try again: ");
    scanf("%d", &input);

    printf("You said... %d\n", input);

    return 0;
}
```

I have a command to compile and run this file from my local WSL:

`sshpass -f pass.txt ssh username@remote.host.address "cd path/to/file/ && gcc get_int.c && a.out"`

When I execute this command, I successfully get the prompt `Give an integer:` and provide one and press enter. Then, however, I do not get the prompt `Try again:`. I can still type an integer (123) and press enter. When I do, it then prints `Try again: You said... 123`

As you can see, no printing occurs until I either `fflush(stdout)` or the program ends. Can I possibly modify my ssh command so that output goes to the local terminal without having to `fflush` before every `scanf`?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to add a [second] `fflush` after the "Try again:" `printf` as you did for the first `printf` You could wrap this `printf`/`fflush` sequence in a macro, or you could set unbuffered using `setbuf`. Or, you could write a wrapper function for `printf` using `...` and `va_start` and `va_end` and `vprintf`

Comment: The title is a bit misleading -- `scanf` actually does not prevent anything...

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica My bad, I agree; just not sure how to phrase the title.

Comment: @CraigEstey It wouldn't hurt I suppose, although it is annoying to have to do flush every time I scan. I'm wondering/asking if there is some way to change my SSH command so output appears correctly without having to flush all the time.

Comment: @jhud No prob, I took the liberty of changing it, I hope to the better. If you don't like it simply revert, no harm done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output to `stdout` does not seem to be flushed when reading from `stdin` on your system in the specific circumstances described. You must flush `stdout` explicitly with `fflush()` before every call to `scanf()`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int input;

    printf("Give an integer: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d", &input);

    printf("Try again: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d", &input);

    printf("You said... %d\n", input);

    return 0;
}
```

Alternately, you can set the output stream as unbuffered and won't need to flush it at all:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int input;

    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    printf("Give an integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &input);

    printf("Try again: ");
    scanf("%d", &input);

    printf("You said... %d\n", input);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Easiest would be to simply set it to unbuffered, I suppose. In this interactive application performance is irrelevant. (Of course, if this is just a proof of concept for non-interactive communication buffering may be essential again.)

Comment: Right, I recognize that for my current setup I have to `fflush` before every `scanf`. This is very tedious, however. My question is: Is there some way to change my SSH command so that I don't ever have to flush stdout?

Comment: @jhud: is manual flushing is tedious due to numerous instances of output, just set the stream as unbuffered as shown in the amended answer.  The flushing issue is probably independent from the `ssh` configuration.

Comment: @chqrlie Love the second solution! If SSH is indeed not the problem, this seems like the best option since it's just one line at the top of main.